# SQL query in an Ant script

Tags: xml, oracle, csv, ant, sybase

I am quite new to Ant script and SQL. Currently I am working on a Ant which contains SQL scripts. The role of the first SQL script is to output a .csv file which will be stored in a particular location and the second script should pick up the values from that file and run it against the database and give me an output. The Ant script is for making sure that the SQL scripts run one by one against the database. My problem is that I don't know how to make the second SQL script to pick up the values from the file that is being generated by the first one. Any ideas?

ps: I am pretty new to all these, so pardon me if I am not able to express my problem in a clear way.

### UPDATE (Taken from OP's comment)

Its Oracle database, I am communicating using Sybase

Here is the SQL script:

```
Select distinct 
    SP_F.trade_id as 'Trade ID'
  , SP_F.issuer_id as 'Issuer ID'
  , SP_R.iSINCode as 'ISIN' 
from t_SP_Fundamentals SP_F 
   , t_SP_References SP_R 
where (SP_F.issuer_id = 3608 or SP_F.issuer_id = 3607) 
      and SP_F.trade_id = SP_R.trade_id
```

Comment: What is the database? How are you communicating with the database? Please show more details (*reduced* code, data structure, sample XML, expected results...)

Comment: @Shnugo
Its Oracle database, I am communicating using Sybase.

Here is the SQL script:

Select distinct
SP_F.trade_id as 'Trade ID',
SP_F.issuer_id as 'Issuer ID',
SP_R.iSINCode as 'ISIN'

from 
t_SP_Fundamentals SP_F
, t_SP_References SP_R
where (SP_F.issuer_id = 3608 
or SP_F.issuer_id = 3607) 
and SP_F.trade_id = SP_R.trade_id
and SP_R.iSINCode in (.......... here is where I enter the data if i do it manually)

Comment: Hi san, I edited your question, please check it out. But I cannot help you. Hope others can...

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for your help mate. Fingers crossed :)